# Application not validating fields Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a problem with validating a large number of fields in the Laravel application, validating fields in a separate class. Above 14 validation fields, no errors are returned to the view with creating a new record. I didn't find anything about it in google. I use Laravel Collective.
Thanks for all the help.

```
public function store(StoreDet $request, Ticket $ticket)
{
    $det = new Det($request->validated());
    $det -> ticket() -> associate($ticket);
    $det -> save();
}
<div class="col-md-2">
  {!! Form::label('truetext', 'Truetext', ['class' => 'control-label']) !!}
  {!! Form::text('truetext', old('truetext'), ['class' => 'form-control ' . ($errors->has('truetext') ? 'is-invalid' : ''), 'placeholder' => 'Type truetext']) !!}
  @error('truetext')
    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
      <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
    </span>
  @enderror
</div>
```

If you need some more code please tell me. I didn't want to add the whole view of creating a new record.

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'det' => ['required', 'unique:dets', new DetCodeCheck, 'max:10'],
        'detname' => ['required', 'max:65'],
        'units' => ['required', 'max:11'],
        'section' => 'required',
        'test' => ['required', new TestCodeCheck, 'max:10'],
        'detorder' => ['required', 'unique:dets', 'integer'],
        'decimal' => ['required', 'integer', 'max:9'],
        'sig_figs' => ['required', 'integer', 'max:9'],
        'rounding' => ['required', 'integer', 'max:9'],
        'hilod' => ['required', 'numeric', 'between:0,99999999.99'],
        'lolod' => 'required',
        'truetext' => ['required_if:datatype,L'],
        'falsetext' => ['required_if:datatype,L'],
        'cascode' => 'required',
        'cascode2' => 'required',
        'cascode3' => 'required',
        'erescode' => 'required',
        'erescode2' => 'required',
        'esdatcode' => 'required',
        'esicas' => 'required',
        'esieddunit' => 'required'
    ];
}
```

}

Comment: this is server side validation or client side.?

Comment: Could you add StoreDet class code ?

Comment: Where is your validation logic? `$request->validated()` asumes that the incoming form request is validated before the controller method is called but you need to define that logic.

Comment: Edited and added code for StoreDet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**required_if:anotherfield,value,...**](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#rule-required-if)

> The field under validation must be present and not empty if the
>   anotherfield field is equal to any value.

Regarding your validation rules in StoreDet class

```
//...
'truetext' => ['required_if:datatype,L'], 
'falsetext' => ['required_if:datatype,L'],
//...
```

`datatype` attr is not defined.

**Fix**

```
//...
'datatype' => ['required|in:....'],
'truetext' => ['required_if:datatype,L'], 
'falsetext' => ['required_if:datatype,L'],
//...
```

Comment: I tested without validation for truetext and falsetext and still didn't work.

Comment: These make sence, because when you remove validation rules for truetext and falsetext you will not get any errors messages for these fields

Comment: When I have only 14 rules for validation and don't fill fields app respond with errors but when I added more validation it don't respond anything and page has been refreshed.

Comment: Try to set SESSION_DRIVER=file in your env file then run php artisan config:clear , delete cookies from browser and try again. seems related https://laracasts.com/index.php/discuss/channels/general-discussion/laravel-5-not-showing-validation-errors-when-textarea-is-filled-with-lots-of-text

Comment: You are genius, it helped. Many thanks for that. So I sending to much data for cookie yes?